# how to remove header from Json file and create a dataframe?

Tags: python, json

I have a .json file and when I read the file, the file comes with a header. Is there a way to
remove the header and create a dataframe out of this .Json file.

file_reading

```
file_reading = json.loads(open('Data/data_audience.json').read())
```

Here the .json file:

```
{'header': {'audience': 'reporting data',
'analysis_type': 'analysis'},
'result': [{'month': 1,
'year': 1997,
'month_year': '01-1997',
'interest_id': 32486,
'average': 11.89,
'index': 6.19,
'rank': 1,
'percentage_rank': 99.86},
{'month': 5,
'year': 1998,
'month_year': '05-1998',
'interest_id': 6106,
'average': 9.93,
'index': 5.31,
'rank': 2,
```

The goal is to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
month month_year  year  interest_id average  index  rank
1      01-1997    1997    32486      11.89   6.19    1
5      05-1998    1998    6106       9.93    5.31    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_reading['result'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   month  year month_year  interest_id  average  index  rank  percentage_rank
0      1  1997    01-1997        32486    11.89   6.19     1            99.86
1      5  1998    05-1998         6106     9.93   5.31     2              NaN
```

Comment: Just make sure to import pandas with ```import pandas as pd```. If it's not installed, install it with ```pip install pandas```.